# some package loading failed in R

Tags: r

I used the same code every time to load necessary packages. But all of a sudden this stopped working.

```
library("knitr") 
.cran_packages  <-  c("ggplot2", "tidyverse" ,"gridExtra", "Rcpp") 
.bioc_packages  <- c("dada2", "phyloseq", "DESeq2", "DECIPHER", "phangorn")

.inst <- .cran_packages %in% installed.packages()
if(any(!.inst)) {
install.packages(.cran_packages[!.inst], dependencies = TRUE)
}

.inst <- .bioc_packages %in% installed.packages()
if(any(!.inst)) {
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite(.bioc_packages[!.inst], dependencies = TRUE, ask = F)
}
sapply(c(.cran_packages, .bioc_packages), require, character.only = TRUE)
set.seed(100)
```

**After running this chunk in RStudio,  I get the following error message....**

```
Loading required package: tidyverse
Error: package or namespace load failed for �tidyverse� in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
there is no package called �glue�

Loading required package: dada2
Error: package or namespace load failed for �dada2� in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
there is no package called �RcppParallel�

Loading required package: phyloseq
Error: package or namespace load failed for �phyloseq� in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
there is no package called �stringi�

Loading required package: DESeq2

Loading required package: GenomicRanges

Loading required package: GenomeInfoDb

Error: package or namespace load failed for �GenomeInfoDb� in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
there is no package called �RCurl�

Failed with error: ‘package ‘GenomeInfoDb’ could not be loaded’

**ggplot2 tidyverse  gridExtra  Rcpp  dada2  phyloseq  DESeq2  DECIPHER  phangorn
  TRUE    FALSE      TRUE       TRUE  FALSE  FALSE     FALSE   TRUE      TRUE**
```

**Could you please let me know how can I fix this to load all packages?**

Comment: Can you restart your R session then try: `install.packages(c("glue", "RcppParallel", "stringi", "RCurl"), dependencies = TRUE)`?

Comment: In the future, you can use `p_load` from `pacman` package for both CRAN and BioConductor packages. It will load and automatically install missing packages if needed https://github.com/trinker/pacman

Comment: Thanks.  It worked